# How to add config clean up policy as "compact" to input topic in below Java code?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

```
//I want to add configuration to input topic 
public void createTopics(Properties envProps) {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put("bootstrap.servers", envProps.getProperty("bootstrap.servers"));
    AdminClient client = AdminClient.create(config);
    
    List<NewTopic> topics = new ArrayList<>();
    topics.add(new NewTopic(
    
    envProps.getProperty("input.topic.name") ,
        Integer.parseInt(envProps.getProperty("input.topic.partitions")),
        Short.parseShort(envProps.getProperty("input.topic.replication.factor"))));
        topics.add(new NewTopic(
            envProps.getProperty("output.topic.name"),
            Integer.parseInt(envProps.getProperty("output.topic.partitions")),
            Short.parseShort(envProps.getProperty("output.topic.replication.factor"))));
    
        client.createTopics(topics);
        client.close();
}
   
public Properties loadEnvProperties(String fileName) throws IOException {
    Properties envProps = new Properties();
    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    envProps.load(input);
    input.close();
    
    return envProps;
}
```

I am able to create the topics. But, I want to configure topic in this code ie., cleanup.policy. How can I incorporate this here?

Comment: Why not use something like Spring-Kafka where it can create topics directly from config file?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the source code for [`kafka-topics --create` here](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/admin/TopicCommand.scala#L225-L246)

As you can see, it calls `NewTopic#configs` with a Map

In that map, you would have `(cleanup.policy, compact)`

You could also call `TopicCommand.main` on your own, rather than re-write most of the existing code.